# Create different JWT authoriser in Auth0 and attach permissions based on the permitted roles

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, aws-api-gateway, auth0, httpapi

There are three kinds of users in my Auth0 tenant:

1. Regular user (no role)
2. Moderator user (assigned "Mod" role)
3. Admin user (assigned "Admin" role)

I created an API in Auth0 and attached to the endpoints via JWT authoriser in the new AWS API Gateway HTTP API.

There is business logic that some endpoints allows only allows regular user and admin, and some allow Mod and Admin. E.g.:

1. Endpoint 1: Allow regular user and Admin
2. Endpoint 2: Allow Mod and Admin
3. Endpoint 3: Allows Mod only

Currently, the authoriser allows any user in the user's database in Auth0, and I check the user's identity within the application via several Auth0's management API:

1. `/userInfo` to make sure the token matches with the `:user_id`.
2. `/oauth/token` to get Auth0 management API access token.
3. `/api/v2/users/:user_id` to get the user profile.
4. `/api/v2/users/:user_id/roles` to get the role.

I believe there should have a better way to handle the identity check. Is it possible to create multiple authoriser with a different role/permission scope (e.g. allow regular user and admin) and attach to the related endpoint accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised there is a `claims` object in `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims` from Lambda according to the [AWS API Gateway Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html).

1. Therefore, the extra `/userInfo` call is unnecessary.
2. I added 2 [Auth0 rules](https://auth0.com/docs/rules) to merge the user role to `user.app_metadata`  and the `claims` object.

Code sample for #2:

```
function assignRoleToAppMetadata (user, context, callback) {
  const ManagementClient = require('auth0@2.19.0').ManagementClient
  const management = new ManagementClient({
    domain: '{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.auth0.com',
    clientId: '{YOUR_NON_INTERACTIVE_CLIENT_ID}',
    clientSecret: '{YOUR_NON_INTERACTIVE_CLIENT_SECRET}'
  })
  const params = { id: user.user_id }
  management.getUserRoles(params)
    .then(roles => {
      user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {}
      user.app_metadata.roles = roles
      return auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
    })
    .then(() => callback(null, user, context))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err.message)
      callback(null, user, context)
    })
}
```

In addition, the following rule attached the role info to `/userInfo`:

```
function(user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'https://{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.auth0.com/'
  context.idToken[namespace + 'roles'] = user.app_metadata.roles
  callback(null, user, context)
}
```